# How to print data after n:th line number

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to get data after the n:th line number.

I have a file with 1500 lines, but I want to print the data after 750 lines.

I tried `head` and `tail`, but couldn't get exactly what I wanted.

Comment: "print"? To the console? On a piece of paper?

Comment: @DeeJayh It is customary to use the verb "print" to mean "to output". Would they want to actually get a hard copy of the output, then it would be trivial to pipe the result to `lp` or equivalent print spooler command. This does not change the what question is asking for.

Comment: I thought tags will be checked, my bad. Trying in bash on linux server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `tail`

```
tail -n +751 file
```

from `man tail`:

> use `-n +NUM` to output starting with line NUM

---

Alternative using `sed`:

```
sed '1,750d' file
```

(`d`elete everything from line 1 to 750)

Answer (score 2):

The `awk` command can be used with operators to specify the number record. In this case greater than (after) record 750.

`awk 'NR>750' input_file_name`

### Detailed explanation

The `awk` command, or its distribution-specific counterparts like `mawk` in ubuntu, are usually available even in the most lean, base distrubitions. An awk program is a sequence of patterns and corresponding actions. The awk program 'NR>750' simply returns all records after line number 750.

Sourced from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678925/5387389

Comment: I think you need `NR>750` as OP wants to print **after** line 750. Maybe that is why the downvote. However, that should be a comment rather than a downvote.

Comment: @pLumo that could be right. I'll update the answer.